# Random crashes while importing Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras (2.3.1) in a script for making 1D-CNN. Running this script locally worked well but when i launched ~200 jobs (all using this script for different input but same model) on server machines , around 10-30% of them crashed while importing keras without any error message.

I share below 2 examples of logs jobs :  when it worked/not worked

this job worked

```
Importing keras...
Using TensorFlow backend.
...done
This is .../Inference.py.
All modules, including keras, have been imported


Model loaded
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 3500, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 3500, 7)           21        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 1750, 7)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 1750, 14)          210       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 875, 14)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12250)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                784064    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 130       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 784,425
Trainable params: 784,425
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Starting inference...
...Inference done
Wrapping up...
done




Inference finished succesfully
```

this one crashed while importing keras

```
Importing keras...
Using TensorFlow backend.




INFERENCE FAILED
```

Here the beginning of the code

```
from array import array
print("Importing keras...")
import keras
print("...done")
import numpy as np
import os
import ROOT
import sys

print("This is %s." %sys.argv[0])
print("All modules, including keras, have been imported")

if __name__=="__main__":
  try:
    ModelFile = sys.argv[1]
    inpFileNm = sys.argv[2]
    outFileNm = sys.argv[3]
  except IndexError:
    sys.exit("Provide 3 arguments to %s" %sys.argv[0])

  if not os.path.isfile(ModelFile):
    sys.exit("Provide an existing model file! EXIT")
  if not os.path.isfile(inpFileNm):
    sys.exit("Provide an existing input file! EXIT")
    
  print("Survived argument checks:")
  print("Model file: %s" %ModelFile)
  print("input file: %s" %inpFileNm)
  print("output file: %s" %outFileNm)

  model = keras.models.load_model(ModelFile)
  print("Model loaded")
  model.summary()
```

and the C++ function i used for executing the python script

```
int Saffron_CNN_Inference(string S2Cluster,string localpath, string postProcessPath)
{
  string pyInfCmd = "python3 "+postProcessPath+"/Inference.py ";
  pyInfCmd += postProcessPath+"/RESULTS/1DCNN_Test_Final.h5 ";
  pyInfCmd += localpath+"Saffron_MakeDataset_"+S2Cluster+" ";
  pyInfCmd += localpath+"New_Saffron_MakeDataset_"+S2Cluster;
  int res = system(pyInfCmd.c_str());
  std::cout<<"\n\n\n"<<std::endl;
  if (res == 0) cout<<"Inference finished succesfully";
  else cout<<"INFERENCE FAILED\n\n\n";
  std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n"<<std::endl;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "crashing without an error message", maybe your code is hiding the errors but we cannot know that since you did not include any code. Please provide all relevant information.

Comment: sorry for that i updated it

Comment: Using std::system does not let you see the standard error stream from the subprocess, which contains the error message from python, why are you even running this from C++?

Comment: curious because the different python errors in the past were in the log files. The issue looks like memory leak when the library keras is imported many times at the same moment because running few jobs (~10) is working well

Comment: We are not into guessing the causes, that is why we ask for more information, if it was a memory leak then you would get a OOM or Out of Memory error.

Comment: Ok the issue was about the version of tensorflow 2.2.0 which use AVX instructions by default for CPU. The jobs which failed were submit to older CPus. The solution is to downgrading TF <=1.5 version or compiling TF from source by expliciting ask no AVX instruction

Comment: In that case you would see Illegal Instruction as error in the error log

Comment: yeah the illegal instruction error appears when we import keras in one of the old cpu but not in the error log, maybe because we run the python script with system as you suggested.